# How to add dynamically class to single < li> when using in Loop

Tags: jquery

I have created pagination using for-loop, so using JQuery how to add dynamically class to < li>. Here is my code:

```
echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
for($i=1; $i<=$number_of_pages; $i++)
{

    echo "<li id='add_class'>"."<a href='first_year.php?p=$i'>".$i."</a>";  

}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: How is that jQuery? How is jQuery suppose to interact with that HTML that is generated?

Comment: the code will render invalid HTML as duplicate identifiers `add_class` will be created

Comment: `add_class` id is getting repeated within for loop. its invalid.

Comment: Yes, id must be unique on page.

Comment: Iam not getting how to write JQuery to pagination class in < ul> my JQuery code is $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(".pagination ").addClass("class");
           
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like below. Consider you want add `active` class

1. add class to first li element

   `$("ul.pagination > li:first").addClass("active");`
2. add class to nth position element (for example position is 5, so you need to pass 4 as index)

   `$("ul.pagination > li:eq(4)").addClass("active");`
3. If you want to add class to all element

   `$("ul.pagination > li").addClass("active");`

Comment: Thanks alot brother its working ..... :)

Comment: Nice to hear from you.. don't forgat to mark as correct. :)

Comment: Complete Code echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
for($i=1; $i<=$number_of_pages; $i++)
{
 
echo "<li class=''>"."<a href='first_year.php?p=$i'>".$i."</a>"; 
 
}
echo "</ul>";
 
 ?>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 
           $("ul.pagination > li:eq(<?php echo $page; ?>)").addClass("active");
   
});
</script>